# PHP 'Where' query conditional on 'If' 'isset'

Tags: php, where-clause, isset

I am new to PHP so any help on the following would be really appreciated:

I am trying to run a query with a WHERE condition, but I only want to apply the where condition if the variable has been set (via a radio button).

I basically want to be able to say - if a variable is not set, do not include it in the where condition. The complication is that I will be doing this with 3+ variables...

At its most basic - here is the code I have so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['category'])){ 
$category = $_POST['category'];}

if(isset($_POST['brand'])) {
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
}

{
$q = 'SELECT name, category, brand, price, imageurl, purchaselink FROM clothes WHERE category = "'.$_POST['category'].'" AND brand = "'.$_POST['brand'].'"';
```

[truncated]

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Build the where clause as a second string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an array, but first of all **DO NOT BUILD QUERIES THIS WAY** since you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql) instead.

The idea is to have a list of suitable conditions:

```
$conds = [ 'brand', 'category', 'name' ];

$where = [ ]; // Empty array

foreach ($conds as $cond) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$cond])) {

        $sql = "({$cond} = ?)";    // We use PDO and bound values.

        $where[$sql] = $_POST[$cond];

        // In *deprecated* MySQL we would use at least
        // $sql = "({$cond} = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$cond]) . "')";
        // $where[$sql] = true;
    }
}
// Now we have a list of pairs:
//     brand = ?     =>  'MyBrand',
//     name  = ?     =>  'MyName',

if (!empty($where)) {
    $sql_string .= ' WHERE (';
    $sql_string .= implode( ' AND ', array_keys($where) );
    $sql_string .= ')';
}

// $sql_string is now SELECT ... WHERE ( (brand=?) AND (name=?) ... )
// Using the MySQL version, we would have ... WHERE ( (brand='MyBrand') AND ... ) )

// With PDO we PREPARE the query using sql_string

// http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-pdo-mysql.html
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

// We need an open PDO connection saved into $pdo

$stmt = $pdo->prepare ($sql_string);

// Then we execute the query.
// Bind the values to array_values($where).
$stmt->execute( array_values($where) );

while ($tuple = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ...
}
```

A shorter way, MySQL only (since it does not distinguish between keys and values) would be

```
$where = [ ]; // empty array()
foreach ($conds as $cond) {
    if (empty($_POST[$cond])) {
        continue;
    }
    // THIS IS NOT SECURE. See e.g. http://johnroach.info/2011/02/17/why-mysql_real_escape_string-isnt-enough-to-stop-sql-injection-attacks/
    $escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$cond]);
    $where[] = "({$cond} = '{$escaped}')";
}
$query = "SELECT ...";
if (!empty($where)) {
    $query .= " WHERE (" . implode(' AND ', $where) . ")";
}
```

This approach has the additional advantage that you can have the 'AND' parameterized - the user can choose whether have the conditions ANDed or ORed via a radiobutton:

```
    $and_or = ('OR' == $_POST['andor']) ? ' OR ' : ' AND ';
    $query .= " WHERE (" . implode($and_or, $where) . ")";
```

Note that the actual value of 'andor' is NOT used -- if it is an OR, all well and good, ' OR ' is used. Anything else that might be accidentally sent in a POST by a customer, such as "[--; DROP TABLE Students;](http://xkcd.com/327/)" , is considered to mean ' AND '.

Comment: I think Mr @Iserni your solution is global and good (this is a good job), but here I think our friend is new in php, he try some thing simple not a strongest security and global with 20 lines of code. but if we want to do things with greated methods I suggeste to use an ORM like Propel or Doctrine. :)

Comment: Thank you Iserni - I definitely want to use PDO but am trying to execute using:                                                     $sql_string->execute();                                                      echo --> then my html code. I am clearly doing something wrong in the execute though - I don't know what thought as I understand that I don't need to bind the variables as this has happened already!

Comment: You can't straight execute `$sql_string`, you need to prepare it as a statement. I've added a couple of links, and the code to use the `$pdo` you create following the manual (second link)

Answer (score 0):

you have to incluide all inside if(){}

```
 if(isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['brand'])){ 
 $q = 'SELECT name, category, brand, price, imageurl, purchaselink FROM clothes WHERE   category = "'.$_POST['category'].'" AND brand = "'.$_POST['brand'].'"';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique to make my filters :

```
$q = 'SELECT name, category, brand, price, imageurl, purchaselink FROM clothes WHERE 1=1 ';


if(isset($_POST['category'])) $q .= ' AND category ="'.$_POST['category'].'"';

if(isset($_POST['brand'])) $q .= ' AND brand = "'.$_POST['brand'].'"';
// here you can add other filters. :) be happy
```

Comment: This is risky if someone sends a value containing quotes (let alone malicious input). At the very least, if not PDO, use escaping.